# reading a table in R?

Tags: r, read.table

I have a txt file with the following structure:

```
NAME     DATA1    DATA2
a        10       1,2,3
b        6        8,9
c        20       5,6,7 ,8
```

The first line represent the header and the data is separated by **tabs**. I need to put the elements of `DATA1` in a list or vector in a way that I can traverse the elements one by one.

Also I need to extract the elements of `DATA2` for each `NAME` and to put them in a list so I can traverse then individually, e.g. get the elements 8,9 for `NAME` b and put it into a list. (Note that the third record has a space in the list in `DATA2` between the `7` and the comma).

How I can do that both operations? I know that I can use `read.table` and `$` for accessing individual elements, but I am stuck.

```
info<-read.table("table1", header=FALSE,sep="\t")
namelist<-list(info$NAME)
```

Comment: When you read in data like this, you'll have a data.frame where NAME and DATA2 are factors and DATA1 are numeric. You can, _post festum_, massage DATA2 into another list by splitting at `,`. Please add more context, maybe there's a better way of doing whatever you're striving to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this demo and look at the structure of `n`, `d1`, and `d2` -- that should help you get going:

```
df = read.table(text="NAME\tDATA1\tDATA2
a\t10\t1,2,3
b\t6\t8,9
c\t20\t5,6,7 ,8", 
                header= TRUE, 
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                sep='\t')

n  = df$NAME
d1 = df$DATA1
d2 = lapply(strsplit(df$DATA2, ","), 
            as.numeric)
names(d2) = n

d2['b'][1] # access first element in list named 'b'

lapply(d2, FUN=mean) # mean of all rows in d2
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @gauden, one problem that I have is with the format of my DATA2 that is "1,2,3","8,9","5,6,7,8" so when I execute the lapply(strsplit...) I got an error because of the " ", how can I get rid of that error? Thanks

Comment: @Manolo, I have edited the code to include parsing the records with the tab separator and this avoids the problem of spaces in `DATA2` causing the error you have discovered.