# strsplit and lapply

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a string in some text of the form `"12,34,77"`, including the quotation marks.

I need to get the values of each of those numbers into a list.  I tried using `lapply` and `strsplit`:

```
control2=lapply(strsplit(data$values,","),as.numeric)
```

but I get the error:

> non character argument

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11470734/1290420) is now answered, and there is no need for extra parsing, `gsub`-bing or `regex`-ing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1) strapply**

**1a) scalar** Here is a one-liner using `strapply` from the gsubfn package:

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- '"12,34,567"'

strapply(x, "\\d+", as.numeric, simplify = c)
## [1]  12  34 567
```

**1b) vectorized** A vectorized version is even simpler -- just remove the `simplify=c` like this:

```
v <- c('"1,2,3"', '"8,9"') # test data
strapply(v, "\\d+", as.numeric)`
```

**2) gsub and scan**

**2a) scalar** and here is a one-linear using `gsub` and `scan`:

```
scan(text = gsub('"', '', x), what = 0, sep = ",")
## Read 3 items
## [1]  12  34 567
```

**2b) vectorized** A vectorized version would involve `lapply`-ing over the components:

```
lapply(v, function(x) scan(text = gsub('"', '', x), what = 0, sep = ","))
```

**3) strsplit**

**3a) scalar** and here is a `strsplit` solution.  Note that we split on both `"` and `,` :

```
as.numeric(strsplit(x, '[",]')[[1]][-1])
## [1]  12  34 567
```

**3b) vectorized** A vectorized solution would, again, involve `lapply`-ing over the components:

```
lapply(v, function(x) as.numeric(strsplit(x, '[",]')[[1]][-1]))
```

**3c) vectorized - simpler** or slightly simpler:

```
lapply(strsplit(gsub('"', '', v), split = ","), as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem may stem from your source data. In any case, if you want to work with numbers, you will have get rid of quotes. I recommend `gsub`.

```
> x <- '"1,3,5"'
> x
[1] "\"1,3,5\""
> x <- gsub("\"", "", x)
> x
[1] "1,3,5"
> as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))
[1] 1 3 5
```

Comment: the solution posted by other user that was: control2=lapply(strsplit(as.character(data$values),","),as.numeric), works just fine. Thanks

Comment: @Manolo Then you don't have quotation marks. :) See? `as.numeric('"9"')`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x <-  "12,34,77"
sapply(strsplit(x, ",")[[1]], as.numeric, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
[1] 12 34 77
```

Since the result of `strsplit()` is a list of lists, you need to extract the first element and pass this to `lapply()`.

---

If, however, your string really containst embedded quotes, you need to remove the embedded quotes first. You can use `gsub()` for this:

```
x <-  '"12,34,77"'
sapply(strsplit(gsub('"', '', x), ",")[[1]], as.numeric, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
[1] 12 34 77
```

Answer (score 2):

As has already been pointed out, you need to regex out the quotation marks first.

The `destring` function in the `taRifx` library will do that (remove any non-numeric characters) and then coerce to numeric:

```
test <- '"12,34,77"'
library(taRifx)
lapply(strsplit(test,","),destring)
[[1]]
[1] 12 34 77
```